# Android: remember string when opening new activity

Tags: android

my activity has a string which gets its value from an intent

```
String myString = intent.getStringExtra("KEY");
```

in this activity I start another activity. From the new activity  I want to return to the previous activity and still have the same value of myString. But when I open a the new activity the value of myString is deleted.

i looked into onSavedInstancState but that doesn't seem to work.

making myString static works but I think that this is not good programming.

So what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: please mark one of the answers as correct which helped you resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ShareDPreferences` to store an object that you want to retrieve later:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("key", ""KEY"); 
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve it later:

```
 pref.getString("key", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html),

> If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd
>   like to save, you should use the SharedPreferences APIs.